# Monitor HTTP Requests from a Flash app

Tags: google-chrome, flash, firefox, network-traffic

I tried Dev tools in Chrome but it is not showing at all.

I am trying to monitor a Chart/Graph App that is getting live Data. Some External monitoring tool is the last resort but I was hoping to use FF/Chrome for the purpose, if possible.

Thanks

Comment: The Dev tools in Chrome is probably showing you the requests by Flash app and you just dont know which of the listed items is a file / data being accessed by the app. After the SWF is listed, is it later followed by an XML file or such? That XML (or JSON, or even PHP) could be feeding the chart data. Also if the data is protected, then a direct file access could fail (shows empty file or requires a user-token etc)

Comment: I could not find as such.

Comment: Can the SWF (only itself) be opened in a new tab? See this **[example SWF](http://vcone.co.uk/public/StackOverflow/PitchShift_v1.swf)** if you open dev tools you'll see the SWF loads one more thing, an MP3 file. So only those 2 things are listed. Isolate your chart SWF in same way and then it'll be easier to see what else it loads. If possible...